# Authorized.net error with Magento2.3.1

Tags: checkout, authorize.net, magento2.3.1, sandbox-mode

I have done the configuration https://prnt.sc/noflvl

Then try to place an order and found below error messages:
https://prnt.sc/nofznb

https://prnt.sc/nofhpp

What is the issue, I created a new developer account on authorized.net but no luck.

I think the issue is due to the "https", As I am testing it on server which is not having ssl.

How can I test Sandbox here?

Comment: Have you viewed your payment log files?

Comment: Order not placed yet, I am stuck on checkout page. No log created.

Comment: Check your browser console for JS errors also check your system.log / exception.log files this will give you a better idea

Comment: I already checked it then I put the screenshots here.

Comment: You can use a free certificate https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: I tried with SSL server but it still the same